# Get datagridview row value from form2 and put in textbox of form1

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a textbox and a button.

When the button is clicked it shows a `DataGridView` which outputs an ID and Name in a separate window (form). These are loaded with select statement from ms-access.

I would like that when I double click on any of the `DataGridView` rows, the ID is transferred to the textbox which is found in the other window (form).

I tried something like this but no success:

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
```

May please someone tell me what should I have on both form as code please?
(new to vb.net so please bear with me and unfortunately I cannot find help)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseDoubleClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString 
    End If
End Sub
```

Note : You use `CellMouseDoubleClick event`

msdn link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedoubleclick.aspx

Comment: It did not work mate. Maybe I need to assign the textbox1 to a variable or something?

Comment: no, you must declare your control in your form, and when you click on your cells, he copy result in textbox